# How can I change Nan values to min value of given data in python

Tags: python, nan

I want to change nan values with the min value of data in Python . But I need to do country match.

[Here is my part of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KvTMZ.png)

There are only nan values in daily_vaccinations column.
I want to see minimum number of vaccined Argentinian instead of Nan. Also this number should change accordingly to the countries. I mean there should be the number of minimum Belgian vaccined instead of Belgium column.

Comment: please provide a code and data sample in plain text

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

Use the imputer from Sklearn and Numpy, in the missing_values parameter in the function specify the nan as shown here.

```
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
import numpy as np

imputer = SimpleImputer(missing_values = np.nan, strategy= 'constant', fill_value = your_value)

# Then you can use the imputer like this

df[["my_column"]]=imputer.fit_transform(df[["my_column"]])
```

Also you can get the minimum value by this command:

```
min_value = df['my_column'].min()
```

Comment: It doesnt work. It take min number of data. But I want min number of Argantinian for nan value of Argantina row.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, you can use the imputer to make all the values numeric then use the min